# Explaning the phrase 「注{ちゅう}目{もく}特{とく}集{しゅう}」

Tags: meaning, compounds

I want to know exactly what the phrase 「注目特集」 means. Part 「注目～」 means "attention, focus" and 「～特集」 - "feature, special issue". I can understand the meaning, but how can I combine them - what is the correct translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "special feature" or "special report" (whence 特集) with a particular focus (whence 注目). Just like in English (I think), it suggests an in-depth report of the topic in question.